# How to avoid Clash of Clans update and go right into the application?

Tags: google-play-store

Whenever I open Clash of Clans, it gives a popup saying,

> **Update is available!**
>
> ---
>
> Good news! A new version of the game is available

There is no cancel option. No matter if I click the back button or tap outside the popup, it always leads me to Play Store page.

How do I avoid update and continue playing?

Comment: It seems there is a version check inside the app. The only thing that I could think of is to use hacked APK, but that can be considered as cheating and thus, illegal and off-topic here. I couldn't provide any answer, you may wait for other answerers if there is a legit way to do that.

Comment: If they have locked it to version checking (entirely possible as it has an online component IIRC) then you will probably have to update it! As Andrew said anything else would be illegal, and again would possibly run into issues like this anyway. Is there any reason you can't update it? Also it might be worth contacting the developer and asking them about this. Use the contact link in the Play Store, not a review.

Comment: @RossC sure. I will.

Answer (score 1):

Bad news: For some apps, especially games, you are not allowed to play without updating it -- especially if it is connected to the net.

You will not be able to legally bypass this restriction.